# Formula for IF statement with NOT CONTAINS error

Tags: formula, sales-cloud, text

I am having issues with a formula that uses `NOT(CONTAINS` and `AND` below:

```
IF(NOT(Contains("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Business_Manager__c)),Business_Manager__c,
    IF(CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Sales_Ops_Contact__c),Acct_Manager__c,
    IF(And(CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL"),Business_Manager__c,
        NOT(CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL")),Sales_Ops_Contact__c,Sales_Ops_Contact__c, NULL))))
```

Receiving 2, expected 1 error.

I have been staring at this for hours and cannot find the issue :/

Comment: can you put the logic you want to achieve

Comment: The goal is to have the statement use each of the TRUE portions for each `IF` statement, `ELSE` null. (True portions are just every "manager" field after each if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONTAINS` operator will take 2 arguments where you were passing one. I think you are trying to achieve like this:

```
IF(
    NOT(Contains("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Business_Manager__c)),
    Business_Manager__c,
    IF(
        CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Sales_Ops_Contact__c),
        Acct_Manager__c,
        IF(
            And(
                CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Business_Manager__c),
                NOT(CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Sales_Ops_Contact__c))),
                Sales_Ops_Contact__c, 
                NULL              
          )
      )
)
```

> Also, instead of using `AND` operator in IF() condition you can use `&&`, that will end up less brackets.

```
IF(
    NOT(Contains("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Business_Manager__c)),
    Business_Manager__c,
    IF(
        CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Sales_Ops_Contact__c),
        Acct_Manager__c,
        IF(CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Business_Manager__c) &&
                NOT(CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Sales_Ops_Contact__c)),
                Sales_Ops_Contact__c, 
                NULL              
          )
      )
)
```

Comment: Teach a man to fish! What were they doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Santanu_Boral , I have tried your suggestion. One thing I changed was the ) at the end of the `NOT(CONTAINS` which needed another Parentheses.  I am still receiving the error. I am not sure if after the `
        `IF(CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Business_Manager__c) &&
                NOT(CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL"),Sales_Ops_Contact__c),
                Sales_Ops_Contact__c, 
                NULL` is correct. This statement should state Sales Ops Contact, ELSE Null for the entire clause.

Comment: I have updated the ans

Answer (score 2):

```
IF(And(CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL"),Business_Manager__c
```

This line here, CONTAINS only has one parameter. You should have the closing parentheses after the next parameter.

```
IF(And(CONTAINS("House:platform SF.API:Chris:NULL",Business_Manager__c),
```